# Firehose out to s3 - re paritition from year month day hour folders format into dt=YY-MM-DD format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, partition

I am working in the AWS EMR ecosystem.

I am looking for smart way to repartition aws firehose output:

s3://bucket/YYYY/MM/DD/HH

into hive partition format

s3://bucket/dt=YY-MM-DD-HH

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Omid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added same answer in Boto3 (to match current lambda default packaging)

```
import re
import boto3

##set buckets:
source_bucket='walla-anagog-us-east-1'
destination_bucket='walla-anagog-eu-west-1'

## regex from from YYYY/MM/DD/HH to dt=YYYY-MM-DD   
##replaced_file = re.sub(r'(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})', r'dt=\1-\2-\3' , file)

client = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
mybucket = s3.Bucket(source_bucket)

for object in mybucket.objects.all():
    replaced_key = re.sub(r'(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})', r'dt=\1-\2-\3' , object.key)
    print(object.key)
    client.copy_object(Bucket=destination_bucket, CopySource=source_bucket+"/"+object.key, Key=replaced_key, ServerSideEncryption='AES256')
    client.delete_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=object.key)
```

Answer (score 1):

We've solved this problem using S3DistCp. We do hourly aggregations of the data, grouping by a pattern, and output to directories that are appropriately prefixed.

This is definitely a feature that is lacking from Firehose, and there is not currently a way to do this using only Firehose.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html

Answer (score 0):

I used python and boto to move the files and repartition them.
i applied a regex to rename key from 
YYYY/MM/DD/HH
To
dt=YY-MM-DD-HH

Code Snippet (notice src key is deleted):

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
import re

conn = S3Connection('xxx','yyy')

##get buckets:
source_bucket='srcBucketName'
destination_bucket='dstBucketName'

src = conn.get_bucket(source_bucket)
dst = conn.get_bucket(destination_bucket)

##Iterate
for key in src.list():
     #print key.name.encode('utf-8')
     file = key.name.encode('utf-8')    

     replaced_file = re.sub(r'(\d{4})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})', r'dt=\1-\2-\3-\4' , file)
     #print replaced_file

     #actual copy    
     dst.copy_key(replaced_file,src.name,file,encrypt_key=True )
     key.delete()
```